# Iterate over a list indexes

Tags: python

I have a list of integers and I want to iterate over it changing some items in place:

```
for i in xrange(len(items)):
    ...
    items[i] += step
```

I don't like this `xrange(len(items))`. I could do `for i, _ in enumerate(items)`, but this is also not perfect.

What do you do in such cases?

Comment: Perhaps a list comprehension? Usually there is a different way to express what you want, but there is not enough context to give you specifics. What exactly is wrong with `xrange()` here?

Comment: Well, where is `...` there is some logic, including a `return`

Comment: Then stick with `xrange()`. It's what I'd use if all I needed was a sequence of indices.

Comment: In my **opinion**, `xrange` looks good here

Comment: `enumerate` would've come out of my keyboard intuitively but `xrange` looks OK as well.

Comment: if your objection is nesting (`xrange(len(some_iterable))`), you could easily write your own function i.e. `def indices(x): return xrange(len(x))`, then `for i in indices(x):`... though not sure it's worth the trouble. The list comprehension is generally the way to do things like this, but as in your case, not always applicable.

Comment: Depending on your logic you could consider writing a generator with `yield` (and eventually combine it with `return`). Please show some details of your `return`-logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension if this is a simple change:

```
items = [x + step for x in items]
```

If you can't write it as a list comprehension, `enumerate` is the way to go:

```
for i, n in enumerate(items):
    ...
    items[i] = n + step
```

Comment: This won't work for him. `...` has a return statement in his code.

Comment: Ok, so use the enumerate. It is the Python way to do it with a list of imutable types to change values inplace.

Comment: `enumerate` is an improvement on `xrange` too, if only because you already have an alias for the referenced item.

Comment: He was ignoring the item reference (with `_`), so my response is an improvement to his code.

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use numpy arrays. with them, it's as easy as:

```
array += step
```